# Is it possible to call an EAR with a script ?(an deployed EAR on jboss 7)

Tags: java, svn, jakarta-ee

I would like to write an SVN pre commit hook script that would be able to call an EAR that is deployed on jboss 7.
I mean that when the script is executed it would be open the web navigator and call the EAR via the (localhost:8080/NameOfTheEar).
It is very important to do it in my project so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT : Thx for the answer. Some details :
The EAR contains my application (in the war module of course) so the action that would do the precommit hook is the same that opening the web browser, writing the "localhost:8080/NameOfTheEar" and clicking on enter. would that be possible ??
In few words, when the script is executed => the application (in the EAR) pops up in a web browser

Comment: Call the EAR doesn't really make a lot of sense.  How exactly are you supposed to call into the remote application?  Does the EAR contain a WAR that hosts Web Services?  If so, you'd want to use a language in your preCommit hook that supports calling remote services using HTTP requests.  Are you actually expecting to call remote objects using RMI?  Then that will dictate what you use to author your preCommit hook.  Unless you provide some specifics about how you need to call into your application, we can't offer much.

Comment: You want to launch a browser **NOT** _call_ an EAR.

Answer (score 0):

Because the limitations of what a preCommit hook can do is based on the language in which you write the hook, you can do just about anything in a preCommit hook.  Most languages would allow a system call to open a Web Page.  I wouldn't imagine it would prevent the commit from occurring.  So there's probably little reason for this to be a preCommit hook.

However, a preCommit hook runs on the machine hosting the Subversion repository.  A hook with this kind of functionality would only work if the working copy committing the changes is on the same physical box that is hosting the repository.  If you have remote clients sending their changes into the repository via svnserve or http, then attempting to display a browser via a preCommit hook will not have any impact on the client machine committing their changes.

I'm not aware of any way to communicate these types of actions back to the client as part of the subversion code itself.  What it sounds like you want is a client-side hook.  TortoiseSVN has a way to [define client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks), but that is specific to TortoiseSVN and is not a repository-based preCommit.  Aliasing in Linux/Unix environments would also be a client-side approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to write a pre commit hook that hits a web page (which seems to be most of what you're asking for). As @EdH says, you pretty much have your choice of language and method for hitting the web page.

You could, for instance, write a shell script that uses curl or wget to hit the page.
Clicking the button could be a bit tricker, depending on what the button does.

If you can simulate the button press by passing the correct parameters to the page (and maybe using POST instead of GET if necessary), then it could be fairly easy.

If you actually need to have the button clicked, you could use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), or some other automated UI testing tool to push the button.

If you're into Groovy, check out [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/)